# python excel subtract with 2 worksheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, subtraction

Is it possible to create a python script to automatic which is subtract cell value with 2 worksheet in one excel file?
I have checked some documents, and seem that use the method of **pandas** or **openpyxl** to do so. But I can't to do that. Do you have any suggestion to me? Many thanks.

Script:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl;

currDateTime = datetime.now()

Sheet1 ="C:\\Users\\peter\\Downloads\\" + currDateTime.strftime('%Y%m%d') + "\\5250A" + "\\5250A.xlsx"
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(Sheet1) 
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0] 
wb4 = xl.load_workbook(Sheet1) 
ws4 = wb4.worksheets[1] 
wb5 = xl.load_workbook(Sheet1) 
ws5 = wb5.create_sheet("Done")

wb4.subtract(wb3)

wb5.save(str(Sheet1))
```

Expected Result:

[image: Figure1]  [image: Figure2] [image: Figure3]

Comment: where did you get the function `substract` from `openpyxl`? and how about trying process the data row by row and save as a new sheet?

Comment: For the process the data row by row, is it use the for loop function to do so? Can you please give me one example for my reference? As I haven't idea how to do that. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do so in excel coule be way easier I think. There could be a smarter way to write this code.

**[NOTE]** I just do the subsctraction cell by cell, so if there's any mismatch like **same row but different dept.id** or **same col but different item** will make errors. If you may meet this situation, you'll have a change some in the following code.

```
import openpyxl as xl

def get_row_values(worksheet):
    """
    return data structure:
    [
        [A1, B1, C1, ...],
        [A2, B2, C2, ...],
        ...
    ]
    """
    result = []
    for i in worksheet.rows:
        row_data = []
        for j in i:
            row_data.append(j.value)
        result.append(row_data)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load excel file
    wb = xl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx')
    ws1 = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws2 = wb.worksheets[1]

    # get data from the first 2 worksheets
    ws1_rows = get_row_values(ws1)
    ws2_rows = get_row_values(ws2)

    # calculate and make a new sheet
    ws_new = wb.create_sheet('Done')
    # insert header
    ws_new.append(ws1_rows[0])
    for row in range(1, len(ws1_rows)):
        # do the substract cell by cell
        row_data = []
        for column, value in enumerate(ws1_rows[row]):
            if column == 0:
                # insert first column
                row_data.append(value)
            else:
                if ws1_rows[row][0] == ws2_rows[row][0]:
                    # process only when first column match
                    row_data.append(value - ws2_rows[row][column])
        ws_new.append(row_data)
    wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```

---

here's my sample excel file

first sheet:

[image]

second sheet:

[image]

generated sheet:

[image]